# Ordering real numbers between 0 and 1 by their decimal expansion?

Tags: real-numbers, cardinals

Writing only the decimal expansion of real numbers I could order them in this way:

1 < 2 < ... < 9 <
01 < 02 < ... < 09 < 10 < ... < 19 < 20 < ... < 98 < 99 <
001 < 002 < ... < 100 < ... < 200 < ... < 900 < ... < 999 <
...
0000000001 < ... < 9999999999
etc.

But where is my flaw of not counting all the reals ?
I mean the decimal expansion of square root of 2 is infinite, so can’t I just claim that I will count it after infinite number of steps ?

Comment: Exactly as you say, you'll never hit anything with infinite decimal expansion (that even includes rational numbers like $\frac 13$). For $\mathbb R$ to be countable you need to be able to make a list of all the real numbers, and each real number should appear at an **actual** position in the list. $\sqrt 2$ just does not appear anywhere in your list. You can't just say "it's at infinity", because that's not a position in the list.

Comment: If you only have finite sequences, then where would $\frac{1}{3}$ be? If you somehow extend this to infinite sequences, then you would end up with $1 < 0.999...$, which can't happen as $1 = 0.999...$ (the "..." here mean "repeated").

Comment: We can compare two real numbers, but there is no complete list in the order, not only because the reals are uncountable. The same problem occurs already in the (countable) rational numbers. Between arbitary rational numbers, there are infinite many other rational numbers. There is no "successor" of a rational number.

Comment: @Peter There is a fundamental difference here. For the rationals we can explicitly construct an order where every rational number has a "successor" (more precisely, a well-order). This will of course not agree with the usual ordering. For the real numbers, we cannot do this explicitly, it requires the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly Cantor's diagonal argument. Assume for the sake of eventual contradiction there is a list or all reals between 0 and 1 (exclude 1 itself), so you can talk about $r_n$, the $n$-th number of your list. They all start $0.\ldots$. For definiteness, forbid numbers ending in an infinite sequence of 9, as $0.59999\ldots = 0.6$ (this leaves out 1). Consider the number $d$, constructed from the list by making it's $k$-th digit different from the $k$-th digit of $r_k$, for example set it to 1 if the $k$-th digit of $r_k$ is not 1, and 2 if the $k$-th digit of $r_k$ is 1. Then $d$ is certainly in the range, it doesn't contain any 9 (let alone an infinite stretch of them at the end), and should be on our list. But it is different in at least one digit of each number on the list. Contradiction, such a list can't exist.

Answer (score -2):

All numbers have infinite digits.

```
0.1 = 0.1000...
0.99 = 0.99000...
```

It's just we have a rule saying if a number ends with infinite zeros, we don't have to write it.

You can change it to 1, by doing so

```
0.1 = 0.1111...
0.99 = 0.99111...
```

And then you can not skip the zeros in
0.7000..., because 0.7 now means 0.7111...

Your list will only contain numbers that ends with infinite zeros with finite list size. Any number that doesn't end with infinite zeros will not in it.

Also, infinite digits means every number contains infinite size of data. Rational numbers that have a repeat pattern, therefore can be represented by finite data size are actually special case.

Comment: $0.1 = 1/10$. But  $0.111\ldots = 1/9.$

Comment: 0.1=1/9 in my example, learn how to read

Comment: Better idea:  Learn how to write.  I'm willing to bet good money that no one knows what you mean when you write $0.1 = 1/9.$

Comment: 0.1=0.1000... in current math rule. What if you make a new rule which replace the zeros with 1? That's exactly what I said? Is this hard to understand? Weird...

Comment: Then you should write 1.1, not 0.1.   And 1.1111... not 0.111...   What you said is not clear, not logical and not consistent, so of course no one understands.